# Load balancer health checks failed for HTTPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check

I have a kubernetes endpoint at MY_IP:80-443 (for HTTP and HTTPS) and I have setup a health check for its loadbalancer looking at port 80. At this moment the endpoint just return 200 OK but the healthcheck keeps saying my pods are unhealthy (marked red).

My question is, is it unhealthy because I just check port 80? But how can I setup health check for port 80 and 443? If I go to https://MY_IP, it returns 200 OK but the browser marked it as Not secure (it does not happen if I access with https://MY_DOMAIN.com), would this be an issue?

Comment: Your browser probably makes it as insecure since the certificate is registered on MY_DOMAIN.com, not MY_IP. You can usually click on the little padlock symbol in the browser and get more information

Comment: Yup I believe so, that's because we don't want people to open the site from IP. But is that causing any problem with health check? Even it returns 200 OK?

Comment: I just found out doing `curl MY_IP:80` gives 301 Moved Permanently while `curl MY_IP:443` 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port. Interesting

Comment: Error code 301 suggests that your URL has been permanently redirected to another URL. Generally, 301 error response include alternative URL to which redirection should occur and the browser will immediately retry the alternative URL. That's could be the reason HC request moving to 443. 

Having said that, have you checked some services is listening to the port 80 or 443 on the back-end to reply health check messages?

Comment: Like I said above, I can access my website from http://MY_DOMAIN which then will be redirected to https://MY_DOMAIN. And on my balancer's frontend is set to port 80-443 so basically I have my service running on port 80 and 443.

Comment: How you configured health check message to the backend services? Are you using GCP LB health checks or sending it through custom application?

Comment: I am just using GCP LB health checks for port 80-443

Comment: Make sure your firewall rules are in place that does allow [access to health check probes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#health_check_source_ips_and_firewall_rules)